# Can someone explain these matrix operations to me?

Tags: matrices

So I have a row reduced echelon form matrix, that is $\begin{bmatrix}
I & F\\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$.

The transpose of this matrix is thus $\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0\\ 
F^T & 0
\end{bmatrix}$.

This is all well and good and makes sense, but why does their product equal to $\begin{bmatrix}
I & F\\ 
F^T & 0
\end{bmatrix}$?

Do you multiply each block matrix like vectors? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the sizes of the corresponding blocks match, then we have
$$\pmatrix{A&B\\C&D}\cdot\pmatrix{X&Y\\U&V}\ = \ \pmatrix{AX+BU & AY+BV\\
CX+DU & CY+DV}\,,$$
which is a consequence of the matrix multiplication.